# Update dynamic lists php mysql Javascript

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, list

I have 2 lists, one for companies and one for sites. Each company has different sites around the country. I am am displaying 2 lists side by side on a modal popup. I have the companies list displaying dynamically from a query all ok, I want the second list to populate with the sites, depending on the company selection from the first list.

[image of both lists side by side as I have it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GElMv.png)

The html element is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
           <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div style="height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll">
                        <div class="list-group" name="companies" id="company">          
                        <!--Call the Showcompany() method from the select.class.php-->
                        <?php echo $opt->ShowCompany(); ?>  
                        </div>                      
                    </div><!--End of first input group-->
                </div><!--End of container-->
            </div><!--End of column-->

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div style="height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll">
                        <div class="list-group" multiple onchange="changeSelection(this.value)" name="sites" id="sites">                        
                        <?php echo $opt->ShowSite(); ?>  
                        </div>   
                    </div><!--End of first input group-->
                </div><!--End of container-->
            </div><!--End of column-->
      </div>
```

This is being populated from a separate included php file as follows:

```
    //function to handle db connectivity
    protected function DbConnect()
    {
        include "db_config.php";
        $this->conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) OR die("Unable to connect to the database");
        mysql_select_db($db,$this->conn) OR die("can not select the database $db");
        return TRUE;
    }

    //function to query the companies and return list for companies list
    public function ShowCompany()
    {

        $sql = "SELECT company.company_name, company.id FROM company ORDER BY company.company_name ASC";
        $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
        $company = '<a class="list-group-item active" value="0">choose...</a>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $company .= '<a class="list-group-item" value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['company_name'] . '</a>';
        }
        return $company;


    }

    //function to query the sites and return list for sites list
    public function ShowSite()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM sites WHERE company_id=$_POST[id]";
        $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
        $site = '<a class="list-group-item" value="0">Select All</a>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $site .= '<a class="list-group-item" value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['site_name'] . '</a>';
        }
        return $site;
    }
```

The jquery I am using to try and populate the second list is as follows this is in my document.ready function.

```
$("#company").change(function(){
    var id = $("#company a:selected").attr('value');
    $.post("select_site.php", {id:id}, function(data){
        $("#sites").html(data);
        });
    });
```

I have had this working when I used select dropdowns and instead of anchor tags I had option tags and it all worked, but it never looked right for what I needed so I decided to make the 2 list views.

The jQuery I had when it worked for my select and option tags was as follows:

```
$("select#company").change(function(){
    var id = $("select#company option:selected").attr('value');
    $.post("select_site.php", {id:id}, function(data){
        $("select#sites").html(data);
        });
    });
```

I won't lie, jQuery is not my biggest strength and I can't for the life of me work out why it won't populate the second list. absolutely any help would be really really appreciated as I have spent the last 3 days trying to figure this out. Thank you.

Comment: Still struggling with this after trying all day yesterday and still no joy getting it to work, I really think its just a simple javascript fix, if you focus your attention to the last part of the question where I switched the jQuery over from select tags to anchor tags, I think this seems to be where I am going wrong.

Comment: Does this data changes often or not?

Comment: There is no `onchange` event available for `div` element; It's available with form elements...

Comment: Thank you @itzmukeshy7 So I can only use on change with form elements and not a div? Is there another way I could populate the second list without using on change?

Comment: You can use the `onclick` event to change content based on the user choice.

Comment: so just change the on change function to an on click function?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 //
 $("select#company").on('click', function(){
     var id = $("select#company option:selected").attr('value');
     $.post("select_site.php", {id:id}, function(data){
         $("select#sites").html(data);
         });
     });
     
    
});

Comment: Tried this and the second list just disappears?